# GroceryCrud Table Relationships set_model (join tables) [EDITED]

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblFacilityHrs` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `uid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
          `description` text,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          KEY `key_uid` (`uid`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

        CREATE TABLE `tblFacilityHrsDateTimes` (
          `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `owner_uid` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
          `startDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
          `endDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
          `startTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
          `endTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
          `days` int(2),
          `recurrence` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
          KEY `fk_fh_owneruid` (`owner_uid`),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_fh_owneruid` FOREIGN KEY (`owner_uid`) REFERENCES `tblFacilityHrs` (`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

> id uid title description location 
>   8ada0ceabd40d509c3fb38f2822a97de11bc6628 Swim Lessons Parent and Child
>   Classes CRC 2 543a6ed0005ff6a0a7fc99cc2f9715d86804ecb0 Swim Lessons
>   Level 1, Session 1  3 7d219b64be6dc706135bdad3e7c2f0d56cb7f353 Swim
>   Lessons Level 2  4 f7c91e2f1daa9c696c22f5aa5736c167d1ba9f94 Swim
>   Lessons Level 3  5 262f06fb75645248162aa983f610ec7959a2011b Swim
>   Lessons Level 4  6 51f9f552ffc5fa4bc8b4e7f914fb22b3b0920c2e Bike 275
>   Participate in this program and take 4 Fitness Cycling classes and get
>   a FREEWaterbottle! Participants can only register 1 time. This is a
>   FREE program! Sign up in the Multipurpose Room. 7
>   0cca3515ec8ee990c863e474fee634ae94d382c2 Passport to Fitness Take
>   Norse Fitness Classes, Get your Passport Stamped and win aFree
>   T-shirt! Take 8 Fitness classes between April 10 and May 1 and get a
>   Free T-shirt.
>
> id owner_uid startDate endDate startTime endTime days recurrance 
>   8ada0ceabd40d509c3fb38f2822a97de11bc6628 4/13/2012 4/13/2012 0:00:00
>   NULL NULL None 2 543a6ed0005ff6a0a7fc99cc2f9715d86804ecb0 NULL NULL
>   12:30:00 2:00:00 2 3 7d219b64be6dc706135bdad3e7c2f0d56cb7f353 NULL
>   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 4 f7c91e2f1daa9c696c22f5aa5736c167d1ba9f94
>   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 5
>   262f06fb75645248162aa983f610ec7959a2011b NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
>   6 51f9f552ffc5fa4bc8b4e7f914fb22b3b0920c2e NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
>   NULL 7 0cca3515ec8ee990c863e474fee634ae94d382c2 NULL NULL NULL NULL
>   NULL NULL

In my controllers folder I have a file named main.php with the following code:

```
...
function fitnessSchedule()
    {
        $this->config->set_item('url_suffix', '');
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_model('schedule_model');
        $crud->set_table('tblFitnessClasses');
        $crud->join_table('tblFitnessClasses','tblFitnessClassDateTimes');
        $crud->columns('title','description','location','startDate','endDate','startTime', 'endTime', 'days', 'recurrance');
        $crud->display_as('title','Event')
             ->display_as('description','Description')
             ->display_as('location','Location')
             ->display_as('startDate','Start Date')
             ->display_as('endDate','End Date')
             ->display_as('startTime','Start Time')
             ->display_as('endTime','End Time');
        $crud->required_fields('title','location');
        $crud->set_subject('Event');              

        $output = $crud->render();
        $this->_example_output($output);    
    }

    function _example_output($output = null)    
    {
        $this->load->view('main_view', $output);    
    }
...
```

In my models folder I have this:

```
<?php
class schedule_model extends grocery_CRUD_Model
{
        function join_table($table1, $table2)
        {
         if($this->$table1 === null)
          return false;

         $select = "{$this->$table1}.*";
         $select .=",$table2.startDate, $table2.endDate, $table2.startTime, $table2.endTime, $table2.days, $table2.recurrence";

         if(!empty($this->relation))
          foreach($this->relation as $relation)
          {
           list($field_name , $related_table , $related_field_title) = $relation;
           $unique_join_name = $this->_unique_join_name($field_name);
           $unique_field_name = $this->_unique_field_name($field_name);

        if(strstr($related_field_title,'{'))
                $select .= ", CONCAT('".str_replace(array('{','}'),array("',COALESCE({$unique_join_name}.",", ''),'"),str_replace("'","\\'",$related_field_title))."') as $unique_field_name";
           else   
                $select .= ", $unique_join_name.$related_field_title as $unique_field_name";

           if($this->field_exists($related_field_title))
                $select .= ", {$this->$table1}.$related_field_title as '{$this->$table1}.$related_field_title'";
          }

         $this->db->select($select, false);


         $this->db->join('uid', '$table2.owner_uid = $table1.uid');

         $results = $this->db->get($this->$table1)->result();

         return $results;
        }

        /* function join_table($table1, $table2)
        {
                $this->db->select('$table1.*');
                $this->db->join('$table2','$table1.uid = $table2.owner_uid','left');
                $this->db->get('$table1');
         }*/
}
?>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method grocery_CRUD::join_table() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\main.php on line
>   234

I'm basically trying to concatenate tblFacilityHrs with tblFacilityHrsDateTimes by way of UID (uid to owner_uid). I want to display both tables at once so that when a user edits the table not only do they edit the event's name/location they also edit its time/date etc.

Reference: http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this forum thread](http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/352-how-to-create-view-for-a-field-from-all-tables-it-is-related-to/), web-johnny states that this functionality is not yet possible.

> This is the 1-1 relation that grocery CRUD doesn't have this
>   functionality yet. It depends of how much time I will have in the
>   future to do that and/or if I have any good donations till then.
>
> This functionality is a big deal and also really complicated to do it,
>   but I think it will save lot of time for many users when it will come
>   up.

Perhaps if you provide what web-johnny deems to be a good donation he might implement it.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific. This can be done with set_model.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question and following is the solution that I did.

1. Create a view with mySQL join statements for the tables that I want to join
2. Look for the state ($cur_state=$crud->getState();) and see if it is either "list,ajaxlist,read or success" and then I set the $crud->set_table('VIEW_NAME');
   and also set the primary key $crud->set_primary_key('KEY','VIEW_NAME');
3. for the else part I use the table name itself so that it will help add,edit operation.

this solution working very nicely.

```
$crud = new grocery_CRUD();
$cur_state=$crud->getState();
$crud->set_subject('Patient Notes');        

/* Use the mySQL view to display the data with related tables */
if(($cur_state=="list") || ($cur_state=="ajaxlist") || ($cur_state=="read") ||     ($cur_state=="success"))     
{
   $crud->set_table('patientsnotes_vw');
   $crud->columns('noteID','Clinic_No','note','noteCreated','username');
   $crud->set_primary_key('noteID','patientsnotes_vw');             

   if($cur_state=="read")
   {
    $crud->unset_fields('noteCreatedBy','user_id','patientID');                      
       }
}
else
{
        /* Use the patient_note table itself for add/edit operation */
        $crud->set_table('patient_notes');
    $crud->columns('noteID','Clinic_No','note','noteCreated','username');
    $crud->required_fields('note');
    $crud->field_type('noteCreatedBy', 'hidden', $this->userID);
    $crud->field_type('patientID', 'hidden', 1);
    $crud->unset_add_fields('noteCreated');
    $crud->unset_edit_fields('noteCreated');        
 }

  $crud->display_as('username','Note Created by');
  $crud->display_as('noteCreated','Note Created at');       
  $output = $crud->render();
```

Answer (score 0):

The class grocery_CRUD ($crud = new grocery_CRUD(); )
Is localed in the folder libraries and you implement join_table in the model.